# Why is JMP used with CALL?

Tags: disassembly, malware, assembly

I am trying to analyze an old malware sample in OllyDbg. It has instruction of the format `CALL <JMP.&KERNEL32.SetUnhandledExceptionFilter>`

I am not an expert in Assembly. I know that CALL is used to call a sub-routine and JMP is used to jump to a particular address in the memory but what is the result of using CALL with JMP? Could anyone clarify on it? Even pointers to where I could find answers would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seeing a call in the form `CALL <JMP.&KERNEL32.SetUnhandledExceptionFilter>` suggests that the binary was compiled with Visual C++'s **[/INCREMENTAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28VS.80%29.aspx)** option, hence the table of jump thunks.

> ... an incrementally linked executable (.exe) file or dynamic-link library (DLL):
>
> ...
>
> - May contain jump thunks to handle relocation of functions to new addresses.
>
> ...

Answer (score 5):

you're right, it could be called directly instead of being jumped after a call.

However, it makes it easier if the address of the API is referenced only once, and this single reference should be a `JMP` (otherwise, it would alter the stack).

So, there is only one memory reference to the API, via a single `JMP`. Each time the API is used, this `JMP` is `CALL`-ed, so execution is transferred transparently, and at the end of the API, the original address of the caller being still on the stack, the caller will be transparently returned to.

Comment: Is this what constitues the Jump table?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is for loading performance - the jumps are gathered into a single region that is made temporarily writable for the purpose of placing the API addresses, and is usually only a single page in size.  This avoids multiple calls to VirtualProtect() by the loader, in order to write all over the code space to every reference to any given API.